# Can you replace an HtmlElement with an HtmlElement in an HtmlDocument?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I am trying to simplify things here for everyone in the office. They have issues all the time with creating new pages and links, images, etc have incorrect code. I want to make it so my program does all that for them.

I am going to have them do all links with a dummy element with data attributes. Then I will just parse the html document when it loads in the `WebBrowserControl` and replace the elements with my own.

I have the `WebBrowser.Document` and I have read through the document and gotten the element to be replaced as an `HtmlElement`. I have created my new `HtmlElement`.

I know the .Replace method does not exist on `HtmlDocument`, but this is what I need to do, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
HtmlDocument document = ManualViewBrowser.Document;
HtmlElement replace = oldElement;
HtmlElement newElement = document.CreateElement("A");

document = document.replace(replace, newElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done by changing the `OuterHtml` value of an old element. Below is an example how to replace `H1` element from https://example.com.

```
ManualViewBrowser.Navigated += (s, e) =>
{
   var document = ManualViewBrowser.Document;
   var oldElement = document.GetElementsByTagName("h1").OfType<HtmlElement>().First();

   // create a new element
   var newElement = document.CreateElement("h1");
   newElement.InnerText = "Hello World!";

   oldElement.OuterHtml = newElement.OuterHtml;
};

ManualViewBrowser.Navigate("http://example.com/");
```